# Cocos2dx 3.17.2 Project size over 10 gb After compiling For android

Tags: android, cmake, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.x

After compiling for Android in Debug and Release APK the compiled files are Taking so much space. is there any way to reduce it?

[image: Main Project Folder]

[image: proj.android]

[image: app folder]
.ccx is taking 5 gb space and .externalNativeBuild taking 2 gb space

Answer (score 0):

The `app/build` is a temporary folder. You can't really reduce the size of it, but if you only want to save disk space you can delete it without any issues as it will be re-generated next time you build the project, though next build time might be increased because of that.